# Finding out how many examples are in a spec file

Tags: rspec2

When I run a spec file (`rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb`) it prints something like `12 examples, 2 failures, 3 pending`.

What's the fastest way to get the `12 examples` part of it? (without running the spec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this and involves the following snippet being add to `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
if ENV['COUNT']
  class RSpec::Core::Example
    def pending; true; end
  end
end
```

This way when I do:

```
COUNT=true rspec spec/controller/posts_controller_spec.rb
```

it assumes all the spec examples are pending and returns:

```
80 examples, 80 pending
```

Of course there is a problem. It doesn't account for all the really pending spec examples but I think it is a *good enough* solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [vrinek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146272/vrinek)'s answer, but for RSpec 3, you can use:

[In `path/to/skip_rspec.rb`]

```
class RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
  define_example_method :it,      :skip => true
  define_example_method :example, :skip => true
  define_example_method :specify, :skip => true
end
```

Command line:

```
$ rspec --require path/to/skip_rspec.rb
```

NB. If you have `config.filter_run_excluding :skip` in your `spec_helper.rb`, you will have to take it out.